# Search using REPLACE in a SELECT with PDO and .MDB ACCESS, with PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to write a mysql query that will match names from a table and the name in the database can contain dots or no dots. So, for example I would like my query string `fast` to match all of these: `fast`, `f.ast`, `f.a.s.t` etc.

I use PHP, with PDO connecting to a .MDB database.

I tried what I found here, with no success (I get error):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE replace(col_name, '.', '') LIKE "%fast%"
```

I think PDO for MDB databases is missing some functions :(
Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried `replace(col_name, '.', '') = "fast"`

Comment: I need to able to search also substrings...so ...i need LIKE and %

Comment: What error you get? Or what is wrong in the result?

Comment: are you searching in a Mysql database (" I'm trying to write a mysql query ") or in MS Access?

Comment: I get error:   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: -3102 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Funzione 'replace' non definita nell'espressione..........in english: FUNCTION "REPLACE" NON DEFINED IN EXPRESSION

Comment: i'm searching in a .MDB database using PHP and PDO.. I'm NOT using MS ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Doug, I solved with:

```
$variable = implode("[.]", str_split($variable)) . "[.]";
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
   col_name  LIKE "%" . $variable ."%";
```

Comment: If you're doing it at a php level you can just do `str_replace('.','',$var);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the `replace()` function unless you are running the query through Access itself. You do however have a possible alternative, try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
       col_name  LIKE "%fast%"
    OR col_name  LIKE "%f[.]a[.]s[.]t%";
```

The square brackets define an optional `.`

Or alternatively do it at PHP level with:

```
str_replace('.','',$var);
```

Comment: no it works the other way around. First you database will search for matching records. Then it will see what columns from those records are requested, or what functions to execute.

Comment: I noticed the mentioning "access" too late. Mysql Access works differenty

Comment: @Doug This way is working well. But I assume to have a variable string every time... so instead of "FAST" I have $variable = "FAST"....or anything else like $variable = "SRL"...then i need to write....LIKE "%" . $variable . "%"   .How can solve?I need to insert via script a [.] after each letter inside $variable?

Comment: @Doug ok solved with: $variable = implode("[.]", str_split($variable)) . "[.]";