# REPLACE version for PHP PDO using Microsoft Access database

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I need to search for a word inside an MDB ACCESS database using PDO and PHP.

The problem is that inside the database I can have a field called CODE_NUMBER and it can contain dot or comma like:

```
12.11.34
```

The user when it search using a custom form for an article in database, maybe search without dots or other special chars... so in the example above, it can write inside the input box something like this:

```
1211
```

Then press enter.

I'd like to get `12.11.34` as a valid result in this case, ignoring search for dot.

The problem is that PDO for MDB ACCESS doesn't support REPLACE command:

This version for mysql is working:

```
    $code = "1211";

    $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT Products.* FROM Products WHERE REPLACE(Products.CODE_NUMBER, ".", "") LIKE ?');
    $rs->execute(array("%" . $code . "%"));
    $ris = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But the same one using MDB access doesn't work!

So I tried this way from here: [Search using REPLACE in a SELECT with PDO and .MDB ACCESS, with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005856/search-using-replace-in-a-select-with-pdo-and-mdb-access-with-php)

```
 $code = "1211";

 $code = implode("[.]", str_split($code )) . "[.]";

 $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT Products.* FROM Products WHERE Products.CODE_NUMBER LIKE ?');
 $rs->execute(array("%" . $code . "%"));
 $ris = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggest?

Comment: Try * wildcard instead of %. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1

Comment: @June7 Hi, thanks but not success...

Comment: So what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Replace() is valid in Access. However, I don't know php/pdo so can't advise on language syntax.

Comment: @June7 no error, simply if I search for $code = "1*[.]2[.]1[.]1[.]*" i don't get any result. Also using % instead *. Replace with PDO not exist :( :( :(